# How to manually import or install a SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to install https://github.com/EspressifApp/EsptouchForIOS to my iOS app. I am able to do it via Cocoapods but there seems to be an issue with installing it via CP and it is recommended to install it manually.

Now I have never 'installed' any library manually in my very limited & short experience with iOS programming. This is how I have been trying -

Adding .h and .m files; and
Dragging Frameworks from the sample project to my project

But it is not working. What else do I need to do for it to integrate with my project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the frameworks to the project

I showed the demo project but you'll need to do it for your project.

[image]

[Download Test Project](https://ufile.io/p6rov3be)

Comment: Did that, also included the files (in the common folder). Since these are .h and .m files, do I import them to my view controller files by import "/common/ESPTools.h" is this correct?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Added a test project where it compiles.